# Drawing a shape with only one coordinate

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry, drag

In JS, I am trying to draw a svg shape based on one point coordinates that I am dragging.
I have a point in the corner of a rectangle.

When dragging this point, the shape follows it and start covering the rectangle.

What I would like is to have something not too rigid, as you can see in the gallery.

When the point is near the opposite corner, the shape recovers almost all the rectangle.

Until it reach the exact opposite corner from its start, and then the shape recovers the rectangle completely.

[Here is the link to the completely image gallery to make it clearer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoaM3.jpg)

I hope this is clear enough. Don't hesitate to ask me for more precisions.

What I need help for is the maths.
I have no idea where to start it ;)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The math depends heavily on what *exactly* you want. The imgur album is *not* clear enough for that.

Comment: Hi @SZenC, thanks for your reply. I did a codepen, but quite far from what I want to achieve : http://codepen.io/extralagence/pen/OMKzqG Does it help ?

Comment: Actually I updated it a bit more, and it is getting closer of what I want. Now I need to find a way to offset the shape correctly...